# Forward only internet traffic through VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, router, openvpn

The title probably needs some work, sorry in advance.

My network is small and consists of a server with one NIC, a desktop computer and a few laptops. There's one wireless router (running OpenWrt) which each client is connected to.

I'm trying to get the connection between the server and the big bad internet bridged through a VPN, but still have local access to the server. I've tried summing up my requirements below:

[image]

Of course, this could easily be done if the server had two NICs and I added another router (set up OpenVPN on one of the routers). However, I'm stuck with one NIC. Is there a way to do this given the current setup? I'm looking to only get internet-bound traffic to go through the VPN.

Comment: If the server and the clients are on the same network/subnet as you vaguely described, then the clients should be able to access the server directly regardless of whatever VPN there is configured on the server or on the router.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't set up another vpn connection interface on your server, have traffic first go to the server and then use a type of ACL to say 'if traffic is for x, go through vpn, else go through standard internet. I think that should work. Otherwise you might be able to do a similar thing depending on the router/modem you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You could create 2 networks in your setup.
Network 1: 192.168.0.0 (Server & its VPN connection).
Network 2: 192.168.1.0 (Clients).
Add a network alias (IP) on your client for access to the server.
Allow the two networks (192.168.0/192.168.1) to NAT through your router to the internet.